# React WebSocket on server, Error during WebSocket handshake

Tags: reactjs, nginx, websocket, plesk

I have made an application that uses a WebSocket. I want to run this application on a PLESK Server, but I get this error message '`WebSocket connection to 'wss://sub.domain.com/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404`' when I visit the website.

After reading a few blogs, I came to the conclusion you have to [adjust](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1942#issuecomment-82352072) something in the NGINX settings, but this also appears to have no effect, or I have to do it wrong, that is also possible. ([Another blog](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html))

At the moment our API is installed on a subdomain (with the NodeJS add-on in plesk) and it also works. As soon as I start up the files locally I can connect to the WebSocket and the API so it must be up to the PLESK Server I think. At this moment only the NGINX 'Proxy mode' is off and the 'Additional nginx directives' empty.

Perhaps one of you is familiar with this problem?